# Prove that the polynomial $P(x_1,x_2...,x_n)=0$ given a set of conditions.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, polynomials, contest-math

Let $P(x_1,...,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}[x_1,...,x_n]$ (i.e. $P$ is a polynomial of real coefficients in $x_1,..,x_n$).

We are given that $\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_1^2}+...+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_n^2}\right)P(x_1,..,x_n)\equiv 0$

and $(x_1^2+x_2^2+...+x_n^2)|P(x_1,...,x_n)$,

Please prove that $P\equiv0$.

Answer (score 1):

Write
$$P(x_1,\dots,x_n)=(x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2)Q(x_1,\dots,x_n)$$
for some polynomial $Q$. Taking the Laplacian on both sides, we get 
$$0=2nQ(x_1,\dots,x_n)+2\sum_{j=1}^nx_j\partial_jQ(x_1,\dots,x_n)+(x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2)\Delta Q.$$
Looking at the leading term for lexicographic order of $Q$, say $c_{\mathbf p}x_1^{p_1}\dots x_n^{p_n}$, we can see that $Q\equiv 0$. Indeed, this term appears $4n+2$-times in the RHS and should be equal to $0$, hence $c_{\mathbf p}=0$.

Comment: I see how you got the second equation, but what do you mean by "Looking at the leading term for lexicographic order"? I don't quite see how $Q=0$ yet. Thank you.

Comment: @user70520 I've edited.

Comment: Thank you. May I know how you got $4n+2$? I see it appears $2n$ times in the first term.